# Wordpress - Custom permalink accept any params

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I need to create a custom permalink structure, I want to show m custom taxonomy in the url, something like:

```
www.example.com/ristoranti/italia/milano/my-post-slug
```

The first segment is the post category, added with WP Categories menu.
`italia` and `milano` are taxonomies created with a custom plugin where `milano` is child of `italia`:

```
function mlt_create_custom_taxonomies()
{
    $labels = [
        'name'              => _x( 'Locations', 'taxonomy general name', 'mlt' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name', 'mlt' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Locations', 'mlt' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Locations', 'mlt' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Location', 'mlt' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:', 'mlt' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Location', 'mlt' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Location', 'mlt' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Location', 'mlt' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Location Name', 'mlt' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Location', 'mlt' ),
    ];

    $args = [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical'        => true, ),
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_tagcloud'       => false,
    ];

    register_taxonomy( 'location', [ 'post' ], $args );
}
add_action('init', 'mlt_create_custom_taxonomies');
```

To add the custom taxonomies to the url I have edited my permalink structure like that:

```
/%category%/%location%/%postname%/
```

I have also added a rewrite rule for `%location%` in order to add the taxonomies:

```
function location_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

    if ('post' == $post->post_type) {
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location' ) ) {                
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $tax_array[] = $term->slug;
            }
            $link = str_replace( '%location%', implode('/',$tax_array), $link );
        }
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'location_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

With this code I'm able to create the link.

The problem is that if I create a fake url like:

`www.example.com/ristoranti/XXXXX/XXXX/my-post-slug` I'm able to see the post, while the `XXXX/XXX` are completely wrong.

How is this possibile? How can I make sure that the taxonomy are correct in the url?

Comment: What's wrong with `www.example.com/milano/my-post-slug`? Why do you need the rest? (FYI, I expect this to be very, very difficult to accomplish - I look forward to seeing if anyone can provide an answer).

Comment: Because I need to create an archive for `ristoranti` and `ristoranti/italia` and so on

Comment: Which would simply live at `www.example.com/ristoranti/my-post-slug` and `www.example.com/italia/my-post-slug`.  Again - why do you need this more complex structure?

Comment: Man I understand your point but my client requested this kind of url for SEO and marketing purpose